# ArcGIS Online can't see legend symbols on mobile

Tags: arcgis-pro, symbology, arcgis-online, legend

I created a simple web map to show bike infrastructure and points of interest. All features were digitized in ArcGIS Pro, published as hosted feature services, and then added to a web map on ArcGIS Online. The map lives here: https://champaigncountybikes.org/bikemap.

As you can see from the screenshot below, the legend for all layers loads and displays correctly when loaded in a browser on desktop.

[image]

However, when users load the map in a mobile browser, the legend does not display the symbols next to different attribute values for each layer (e.g., bike lane = pink line).

I have tried removing and re-adding all layers just in case a change I made in the web map messed up the legend entries.  I've also tried modifying the symbology in the web map to use different styles than those inherited from the original layers in ArcGIS Pro. Nothing seems to fix it.

Has anyone else encountered this issue or know a workaround or fix? Thanks.

[image]